# How to combine different querys with different conditions

Tags: mysql

I've three tables: a, b and c
a:(q,r,s), b:(q,r,t), c:(q,r,u,v)
I want to make a query like this:

```
    select q,r from a where s="whatever", q="whatever"
    select q,r from b where t="whatever", q="whatever"
    select q,r from c where u="whatever", q="whatever"
```

I want the results in one query, order by r. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL UNION operator. It is used to combine the result sets of 2 or more SELECT statements. It removes duplicate rows between the various SELECT statements.

**Each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of fields in the result sets with similar data types.**

Example:

```
select q,r from a where s="whatever", q="whatever"
UNION
select q,r from b where t="whatever", q="whatever"
UNION
select q,r from c where u="whatever", q="whatever"
ORDER BY 1 -- If you want to order by specific colum and columns'name are different in the two select
```

You can use UNION ALL instead of UNION. The difference between them is that **UNION ALL** does not remove duplicate rows.

Comment: I want the total result ordered by a common column

Comment: If the column names are different between the two SELECT statements, it is more advantageous to reference the columns in the ORDER BY clause by their position in the result set. In the example above I'm ordering by field # 1 no matter the name.